# What are the criteria for activities to be reused in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activities which can be reused for different data by defining the Extras. For example for traversing a hierarchy of data. Say activities are A and B, with extras in brackets.

So in the app I navigate A(1), A(2), A(3), B(1), A(1)

Should the original class A(1) be reused instead of creating a new instance, can this be made to do so because at the moment it is recreating a new instance every time.

I have been looking at the launch flags, but have not found the correct combination (if there is one).

Comment: Is it possible to navigate **BACK** form A(2) to A(1)

Comment: Navigation works fine, A(2) to A(1) yes. but when the second A(2) fires it is a new instance.

Comment: When you go from B(1) to A(1), do you want to remove A(2), A(3) and B(1) from the stack?

Comment: I was not going to remove then, so back always goes back, but this is something I have been thinking about as the x(1) items will be accesses via the activity bar buttons/menu.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Task Launch Modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) to learn how you can control the instantiation of new activities. It seems that what you're looking for is not strictly possible because it would create a very confusing back history (from a user's perspective).

You can reuse an activity, if it is at the top of the stack using `singleTop`. `singleTask` might also do what you want.

> **"singleTop"** If an instance of the activity already exists at the top
> of the current task, the system routes the intent to that instance
> through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new
> instance of the activity. The activity can be instantiated multiple
> times, each instance can belong to different tasks, and one task can
> have multiple instances (but only if the activity at the top of the
> back stack is not an existing instance of the activity). For example,
> suppose a task's back stack consists of root activity A with
> activities B, C, and D on top (the stack is A-B-C-D; D is on top). An
> intent arrives for an activity of type D. If D has the default
> "standard" launch mode, a new instance of the class is launched and
> the stack becomes A-B-C-D-D. However, if D's launch mode is
> "singleTop", the existing instance of D receives the intent through
> onNewIntent(), because it's at the top of the stack—the stack remains
> A-B-C-D. However, if an intent arrives for an activity of type B, then
> a new instance of B is added to the stack, even if its launch mode is
> "singleTop".
>
> Note: When a new instance of an activity is created, the user can
> press the Back button to return to the previous activity. But when an
> existing instance of an activity handles a new intent, the user cannot
> press the Back button to return to the state of the activity before
> the new intent arrived in onNewIntent().
>
> **"singleTask"** The system creates a new task and instantiates the
> activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the
> activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the
> intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent()
> method, rather than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the
> activity can exist at a time. Note: Although the activity starts in a
> new task, the Back button still returns the user to the previous
> activity.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes

Comment: The back history is not confusing, as I am traversing a hierarchy, so it made sense to write an activity which could be parameterised. singleTop does not work for me because I want to be able to go from A to A for example. singleTask similarly does not work in my situation. I had looked at the launch modes, but as you say, perhaps  it is not possible in my example.